# Correcta navegación entre pantallas en Flutter

Tags: flutter

No puedo hacer una correcta navegación entre pantallas.

**Tengo la primer pantalla**, que contiene una lista con un FutureBuilder.

Cuando se presione un botton, debería de pasar a la segunda pantalla con el siguiente código:

```
Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => pantalla_lista(categoria: cat.id));
       Navigator.push(context, route);
```

Donde paso como parametro un id.

**En la segunda pantalla** tengo otra lista, de la misma característica que la primera. Cuando se presiona un elemento pasa a la tercer pantalla.

```
onTap: (){ 

         Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeTrips(value: negocio));

        Navigator.push(context, route);}
```

Cuando presione en volver, me vuelve al inicio del todo. Salteando pantallas.

En principio, me gustaría saber como corregir este error, y como podría que cuando este en la ultima pantalla y vuelva una pantalla para atrás, estar en el scroll donde había dejado.

Espero que se entienda. Saludos!

Comment: `Navigator.of(context).push(ruta)`. Usa eso. Si tienes problemas edita la pregunta.

Comment: seguro que no usas replace en lugar de push? , trata de replicar el error en un proyecto simple de navegación de pantallas

Comment: @diegoveloper con el replace se debería de solucionar? y como es su sintaxis ?

Comment: no, el replace reemplaza pantallas, lo que tu quieres es que al presionar back, regresas a la pantalla anterior, no a la pantalla inicial , cierto?

Si tienes algún repo donde se pueda probar tu código, me parece extrañol o que mencionas.

Comment: Si quiero eso, lo que mencionas, y no lo tengo en ningún repo actualizado. :/

Comment: Crea un proyecto flutter de 0 super básico, crea la navegación entre esas pantallas y verifica que todo funcione bien (hazlo en un solo archivo), si aún así te falla, agrega el código aquí : https://gist.github.com/  y lo pones para verificar el error